# Confusion about the interface

Tags: solidity, contract-development, erc-721

Let's say there is an interface:

**IERC721.sol**

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

interface IERC721 {
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 tokenId) external;
}
```

and the implementation of it:

**MyContract.sol**

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "./IERC721.sol";

contract SimplePaymentWithRoyalty {
    struct Info {
        address token;
        uint tokenId;
    }

    uint _id;
    mapping (uint => Info) private _tokens;
    
    function listToken(address token, uint tokenId) external {
        IERC721(token).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), tokenId); // how does this work?

        Info memory info = Info(
            token,
            tokenId,
        );

        _id++;
        _tokens[_id] = info;
    }
}
```

I'm confused about two things:

1. How does the `IERC721` interface know the implementation of `transferFrom`, which is:

```
function transferFrom(
    address from,
    address to,
    uint256 tokenId
) public virtual override {
    //solhint-disable-next-line max-line-length
    require(_isApprovedOrOwner(_msgSender(), tokenId), "ERC721: transfer caller is not owner nor approved");

    _transfer(from, to, tokenId);
}
```

2. What does `IERC721(token)` mean? There is no constructor or a variable in `IERC721.sol`. And what role does the address `token` play in `transferFrom`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ERC721 implemented here https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol, IERC721 gets an address of deployed ERC721 and let you interact with it.

Comment: ok so the `token` in `IERC721(token)` is the address of the deployed `ERC721`? And does the interface have an automatic constructor?

Comment: Yes, and for `transferFrom` `msg.sender` should approved `address(this)` before transfering `tokenId`

Comment: is there an ERC721 contract that's been deployed by Open Zeppelin that people can use?

Comment: No but you can create your own on every testnet to test your code

Answer (score 0):

For your question 2, IERC721(token) converts `token` as the contract type of ERC721, it is not a constructor :) as in solidity, as most of the OOP language, interface does not have constructor